# Display mercurial version with CGI

Tags: mercurial, cgi

I'm using mercurial on a shared hosting with hgwebdir cgi script.

Sometimes I'd like to check which version of mercurial is there installed on the server.
Is there any way to display mercurial version using CGI (like output of `hg --version`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ReferenceCycles

```
from mercurial import hg, ui, util
import os
import gc

def test():
    print "Mercurial version: %s" % util.version()
    repo = hg.repository(ui.ui(), os.getcwd())
    status = repo.status()
    print status

test()
print "gc.collect() returns %s" % gc.collect()
```